# WCF Divide WSDL By Operation Based

Tags: c#, wcf, wsdl

I have one WCFServiceOperation which has n different Operations.Is it possible to get single operation wsdl

WCFServiceOpearation-->MyOperation 1,MyOperation2,MyOperation3

when I get WCFServiceOperation.svc this time I get all them ,what I want that

something like that WCFServiceOperation.svc?op=MyOperation2 that time my wsdl only includes MyOperation2 .

Comment: Write a [WSDLExportExtension](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carlosfigueira/2011/10/05/wcf-extensibility-wsdl-export-extension/)

Answer (score 0):

The low Tech way to do this is to create a wsdl for each operation.

You can still keep the main wsdl With all the operations.

What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes ,I have done it as you said?what is the high tech way?

Comment: The high Tech solution would be rene's comment to the question.